# Firebase Database - db.off() is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a reference to the Firebase Realtime Database:

```js
var db = firebase.database();
```

and an event listener attached:

```js
db
.ref(/* removed for privacy reasons */)
.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let val = snapshot.val();
    /* removed for privacy reasons */
});
```

I need to detach this listener when the user logs out. The Firebase docs say:

> Callbacks are removed by calling the off() method on your Firebase database reference.

However, when I try to detach it, I get an error.

```js
db.off();
// TypeError: db.off is not a function
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `off()` call exists on a [`Query`/`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#off), not on the database as a while.

So:

```
db
.ref(/* removed for privacy reasons */)
.off()
```